# STM32: How can i poll a GPIO pin until 100ms using timer interrupt?

Tags: stm32, timer, interrupts

I am currently use nucleo-board and I try to poll a pin until 100ms. I activated timer interrupt. So basically if pin is not high (digital '1') until 100ms the function must returns false. I share my algorithm below. All I need is to know where to check if interrupt is occur or not.

```
pin = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_12);
if(HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}
while(pin != GPIO_PIN_SET)
{
    pin = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_12);
    {
        if(HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your timer speed, you can counter for 100ms and raise a flag to get into your if state. For example, if your timer speed is 400kHz(0.0025ms period), the timer interrupt will interrupt every 0.0025ms and start to count until it reaches 100ms and reset it.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT` does. It doesn't ask the question "has my timer stopped?", it commands the timer "stop now".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are already running the systick timer which ticks every 1ms, so you can just use the HAL_GetTick() to read the millisecond count.

Answer (score 1):

Most basic implementation of this doesn't need an interrupt. You can set your timer to 100ms (trigger update event every 100ms, prescaler, reload value and counter values of the timer must be selected accordingly).

Here is some idea of how to change algorithm (pseudo-code):

```
if(timer_update_event_occurred()) 
{
   disable_timer(); //(if you don't need it anymore);
   break;
}
```

inside the polling loop.

Alternatively (pseudo-code)

```
while(pin != GPIO_PIN_SET && !timer_update_event_occurred()){
   keep_polling();
}
disable_timer_if_you_don't_need_it_anymore();
```

"Timer update event occurred" is just a bit in the timer register. It is set to "1" when update event happens. Update event = counter reaches its max value and resets to count from the start again (which must happen after 100ms).

If you want to check that bit directly, you can use (actual code):

`if(TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF)`

this is true (value of a number (TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) is not zero) when timer had an update event. So this will become true after 100ms if timer is set up correctly. Unlike my pseudo-code above, this line is an actual working code. So you'll be basically polling Timer2 -> Status Register (SR) -> Update event happened bit "did 100ms pass?".

Warning: if you need that timer again, you need to reset that bit manually right after finding 1 in there (it's better to always have this line anyway. Clearing flags is a good habit, and often a necessity).

`TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; //clear update event flag`

If you're not familiar with bitwise operations, this is a good moment to learn it. It's actually short and easy, albeit a little confusing at first.

The problem with the interrupt is that it operates outside the scope of your polling function. It has no connection to it, your polling function has no way to send or receive any information from the interrupt function. You CAN set an interrupt, but then you will need a global variable that you will have to poll in your GPIO polling loop, that interrupt will change - something interrupt handler function and your polling function both can access, to signal to the polling loop that it's done. Given you have a polling loop for the GPIO anyway and your MCU is busy polling GPIO all the time, there is no practical advantage to interrupt. Unnecessary overcomplication (although it will work of course). Also, global variables are generally frowned upon if there is a way to get away without them. They permanently take RAM. Not an issue for a small scale project, but it's better not to form bad habits.

Short googling didn't return any way to check if the event occurred via HAL. But all it would do (if it existed) is pretty much that little line of code that I presented. It is exactly that bit in the register becoming 1 that triggers timer interrupt, if interrupt is activated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, makes my issue easier. For now, I added a flag to TIM2_IRQHandler function and I reset this flag end of the my polling loop. I ended up no issues rigth now. Best regards.